# Can we receive webhooks from Foundry when a dataset updates?

Tags: palantir-foundry

Can Foundry we receive Webhook calls to an arbitrary external endpoint when a dataset updates (e.g. new transaction committed, or jobspec updated)?

Answer (score 0):

I checked around and couldn't find any hooks, maybe there is something at actions level, but that is downstream from transactions.

Alternatively you can workaround it by having a downstream transform that just exists to build once upstream has transactions, and use it to make  said http requests from your transforms via the driver. I understand it's not the same as you requested, but it's the best workaround I can think of.

You'll have to request via your support to have whatever endpoint you want white listed within Foundry Configuration. This will likely have to be applied by Palantir, and it will raise security questions, so you should reach out internally via your support mechanisms.

Once you do that, something like this should work.

```py
import requests

@transform_df(
   _noop_df=Input("your upstream"),
   Output("output dataset"))
def transform(_noop_df):
   req = requests.Request('POST','http://stackoverflow.com',headers={'X-Custom':'Test'},data='a=1&b=2')
   # write the result of the request into the output if you want.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was hoping there might be something more out-of-the-box to integrate foundry with other parts of our data ecosystem. Since git Webhooks are supported for Code Repository changes and I assume internally foundry uses an event driven service as well, I assumed that there might be something available.  I have created a feature request via my support channels.

Comment: you may be able to use a magritte rest task export to hit an api after your transform builds, instead of using a transform

Comment: Thanks, also a good option. I am more looking for a first class primitive though.